# Defining Node shape in a Network plot with an additional attribute table in R

Tags: r, igraph, ggnet2

I am working on plotting a Network and it contains two different types of Nodes which I want to visualise with different shapes. For that I made an additional table in which I specified which structure is which type using a binary system. Now I want to specify in my plot function that the structures with 1 are to be triangles and the ones with 0 as circles.
My data for the Network is in the format of an adjacency matrix (I use igraph) and I am using ggnet2 for the plotting of it.

this is how I imported the data:

```
am <- as.matrix(read.csv2("mydata.csv", header = T, row.names = 1))
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(am, mode = "undirected")
attr <- read.csv2("myattributes.csv", header = T, row.names = 1)
```

this is how I would plot it but I dont know how to specify the `shape` function

```
ggnet2(g, size = "degree", node.color = "darkgreen", shape = ??????)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the package-requirements for plotting `igraph`s with `ggnet2` include `ggplot2`, `sna` and `network` as well as `intergraph` as a bridge.

ggnet2 is prettier, sure, but the `igraph`-way is this:

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(100,100,'gnm')
V(g)$shape <- sample(c('csquare','circle'), 100, replace=T)
plot(g, vertex.label = NA)
```

Note that I added two `igraph`-style shapes as vertex-attributes to `g` above. In `ggent2` you can provide a vector with shapes, but they can be any values (even a factor), or numbers (the usual gray circle is `19`. Try this out to plot in `ggnet2`

```
ggnet2(g, shape=19)
ggnet2(g, shape=10+round(1:100/10))
ggnet2(g, shape=factor(V(g)$shape))
V(g)$shape <- sample(c('One shape','Another shape'), 100, replace=T)
ggnet2(g, shape=V(g)$shape, size = "degree", node.color = "darkgreen")
```

Note that, if you add attributes to your vertices after separately loading attribute data (as you do above), it may be so that the very *order* of your data matters. Make sure your table import actually works as intended with the correct attribute being assigned to the correct vertex. I find it a good practice to tie all values as attributes on the igraph-object (edge- and vertex attributes alike) rather than letting the network data live in different dataframes or loose vectors to be combined in order to correctly visualise a network.